# __declspec(align(#)) on the heap

Tags: c++, alignment, memory-alignment

How would you align objects allocated on the heap similar to __declspec(align(#))? This include arrays, so it is not an option to just add the alignment to the class

```
class SomeClass
{
    //Something
}

//Somewhere
a = new SomeClass[20] //aligned to 64 bytes
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the standard `alignas` attribute?

Comment: I only required the first element of an array to be aligned. Every element being 64 byte aligned would be a waste of space. I probably should when I want something like that though.

Comment: So you aren't limited by the C++ version you use?

Comment: Not really. I can mostly use C++ 17.

Comment: Please, elaborate how `alignas` doesn't do the same as `__declspec(align(#))` with respect to arrays. Example would help.
If you really need the start of an array aligned, but not each element, then use `operator new(size_t, align_val_t)` followed by placement new on returned pointer.

Comment: The two specifiers would do the same thing, which is not what I need.

Comment: Does operator new with align_val_t work that way? I can't find any specific information on that.

Comment: @me': It looks like a valid answer to me (shouldn't have been a comment). You don't want to align `SomeClass`; aligning the memory allocation seems to be exactly what you want. Just try it; if it works for you you can self-answer and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

__declspec(align()) only works for objects with static lifetime, if you need alignment greater than that provided by new you will have to use a specialized allocator that can handle doing so (using _aligned_malloc or VirtualAlloc for example).

_aligned_malloc allows you to specify the needed alignment while VirtualAlloc uses the system allocation granularity (which is 64k on all versions of windows I am aware of, certainly it is  a large value when compared against most allocations).

Comment: Wouldn't that involve overloading operator new and operator delete (because these are classes)?